# How can MongoDB dataSize be larger than storageSize?

Tags: mongodb

As far as I understand, the storage size for MongoDB should always be larger than data size. However, after upgrading to Mongo 3.0 and using WiredTiger, I start seeing that the data size is larger than the storage size.

Here's from one of the databases:

```
{ 
    "db" : "Results", 
    "collections" : NumberInt(1), 
    "objects" : NumberInt(251816), 
    "avgObjSize" : 804.4109548241573, 
    "dataSize" : NumberInt(202563549), 
    "storageSize" : NumberInt(53755904), 
    "numExtents" : NumberInt(0), 
    "indexes" : NumberInt(5), 
    "indexSize" : NumberInt(41013248), 
    "ok" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

Note that 202563549 > 53755904 by far margin. I am confused how this can be. Is the way to read `db.stats()` different now in Mongo 3.0?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The storageSize metric is equal to the size (in bytes) of all the data extents in the database. Without compression, this number is larger than dataSize because it includes yet-unused space (in data extents) and space vacated by deleted or moved documents within extents. However, as you are using the `WiredTiger` storage engine, data is compressed on the disk and is therefore smaller than the dataSize.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB 3.0 with WiredTiger engine uses 'snappy' compression by default.
If this affects your DB performance, you can consider to turn it off (blockCompressor: none) in the **mongod.conf** file:

```
storage:
  engine: wiredTiger
  wiredTiger:
    collectionConfig:
      blockCompressor: none
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does not hurt the performance but I originally had a metric that uses numbers from dbstats to keep track of different sizes of the database, and the metrics start looking a bit funny after I upgraded to 3.0.