# What are the meanings of "storageSize" and "size" for a collection's sizes in MongoDB 3.2?

Tags: mongodb

About the statistics of a collection

1. From MongoDB: The Definite Guide, 2ed, by Kristina Chodorow, 2013,
   which I guess uses MongoDB 2.4.0, it says that "storageSize" is
   greater than "size"

   > For seeing information about a whole collection, there is a stats function:

   ```
   > db.boards.stats()
   {
       "ns" : "brains.boards",
       "count" : 12,
       "size" : 32292,
       "avgObjSize" : 2691,
       "storageSize" : 270336,
       "numExtents" : 3,
       "nindexes" : 2,
       "lastExtentSize" : 212992,
       "paddingFactor" : 1.0099999999999825,
       "flags" : 1,
       "totalIndexSize" : 16352,
       "indexSizes" : {
           "_id_" : 8176,
           "username_1_slug_1" : 8176
       },
       "ok" : 1
   }
   ```

   > "size" is what you’d get if you called Object.bsonsize() on each
   >   element in the collection and added up all the sizes: it’s the actual
   >   number of bytes the document in the collection are taking up.
   >   Equivalently, if you take the "avgObjSize" and multiply it by "count",
   >   you’ll get "size".
   >
   > As mentioned above, a total count of the documents’ bytes leaves out
   >   some important space a collection uses: the padding around each
   >   document and the indexes. "storage Size" not only includes those, but
   >   also empty space that has been set aside for the collection but not
   >   yet used. Collections always have empty space at the “end” so that new
   >   documents can be added quickly.
2. On my local computer, I experiment with MongoDB 3.2 to get the
   statistics of a collection, and find that "storageSize" is smaller
   than "size"

   ```
   > db.c20160712.stats(1024)
   {
       "ns" : "TVFS.c20160712",
       "count" : 2305,
       "size" : 231,
       "avgObjSize" : 102,
       "storageSize" : 80,
   ...
   ```

Do the meanings of "storageSize" and "size" change in MongoDB 3.2 from 2.x?

If yes, what do they mean in 3.2?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the WiredTiger storage engine? If so, its data compression will typically make `storageSize` smaller than `size`.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure. How can I check it?

Comment: `db.serverStatus().storageEngine`

Comment: Yes, i am using it. Why doesn't compression apply to both? Can you cite the source mentioning that?

Comment: Looks like there's a dupe for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054780/how-can-mongodb-datasize-be-larger-than-storagesize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can MongoDB dataSize be larger than storageSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054780/how-can-mongodb-datasize-be-larger-than-storagesize)