# Command to check MongoDB database size

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to check the space on the current MongoDB Replica set on AWS to migrate it to AWS DocumentDB. I get the below output when I run db.stats() command from the one of the Primary set. But which is the actual DB size?

```
"db" : "Test",
        "collections" : 12,
        "objects" : 10889814,
        "avgObjSize" : 21885,
        "dataSize" : 238334118124,
        "storageSize" : 239889897792,
        "numExtents" : 179,
        "indexes" : 18,
        "indexSize" : 2404561600,
        "fileSize" : 244627537920,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
```

Comment: [What is difference between “size” and “storageSize” displayed by Mongo stats() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345630/what-is-difference-between-size-and-storagesize-displayed-by-mongo-stats-f) and [How can MongoDB dataSize be larger than storageSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054780/how-can-mongodb-datasize-be-larger-than-storagesize/34054893).

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbStats.dataSize

Answer (score 6):

By running the following command you will get the storage statistics of database.

```
db.runCommand( {
   dbStats: 1      
} )
```

Result---

```
/* 1 */
{
    "db" : "play",
    "collections" : 34,
    "views" : 0,
    "objects" : 96,
    "avgObjSize" : 1015.25,
    "dataSize" : 97464.0,
    "storageSize" : 1056768.0,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 49,
    "indexSize" : 1306624.0,
    "scaleFactor" : 1.0,
    "fsUsedSize" : 84943761408.0,
    "fsTotalSize" : 117088358400.0,
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1593430884, 35),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "HLikK1PgZasDWNGQxS94TSuniog=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(6824032301186285572)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1593430884, 35)
}
```

the documentation : [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/)

here:

> `dbStats.dataSize`
>
> The total size of the uncompressed data held in this database. The dataSize decreases when you remove documents.
>
> For databases using the WiredTiger storage engine, dataSize may be larger than storageSize if compression is enabled. The dataSize
> decreases when documents shrink.
>
> `dbStats.storageSize`
>
> The total amount of space allocated to collections in this database for document storage. The storageSize does not decrease as
> you remove or shrink documents. This value may be smaller than
> dataSize for databases using the WiredTiger storage engine with
> compression enabled.
>
> `dbStats.numExtents`
>
> Contains a count of the number of extents in the database across all collections.

Comment: Thank John! But Do you know what is the unit of `dataSize`? I mean b, kb or MB ?

Comment: Bytes, but you can also look it in kb, by setting another extra field scale: e.g `db.runCommand( {
   dbStats: 1,
  scale: 1024     
} )`

Comment: @John What is value for scale if I want stats in MB or GB ?

Comment: @VishalJamdade you can type `1024 * 1024` or `1048576` as scale

Answer (score 0):

DataSize is uncompressed size of data of the database.

Storage size is total space allotted to the collections in the database.

Totalsize is where mongo stores data in the filesystem

So you would check Totalsize to get an idea how much your database grows.

> **dbStats.dataSize**
>
> The total size of the uncompressed data held in this database. The dataSize decreases when you remove documents.
>
> For databases using the WiredTiger storage engine, dataSize may be larger than storageSize if compression is enabled. The dataSize decreases when documents shrink.
>
> **dbStats.storageSize**
> The total amount of space allocated to collections in this database for document storage. The storageSize does not decrease as you remove or shrink documents. This value may be smaller than dataSize for databases using the WiredTiger storage engine with compression enabled.

> **dbStats.fsUsedSize**
> New in version 3.6.
> Total size of all disk space in use on the filesystem where MongoDB stores data